# Get current customer collection in custom account navigation link

Tags: customer, customer-account, helper, customer-session

I have created the custom link in customer account left navigation. I am successfully created it.

I am trying to get current customer Data in template file. I am getting 500 server error. Below is the code i used in my block file

```
 class Lists extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
 {
  protected $helperData;
  public function __construct(
    \[vendor]\[Module]\Helper\Data $helperData,
  ) {
        $this->helperData = $helperData;
  }
  public function _prepareLayout()
   {
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
   }

  public function currentCustomer(){
    return $this->helperData->getCurrentCustomer();
  }
```

}

Used like below in template file.

```
$customerObj = $this->currentCustomer();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($customerObj);die;
```

Helper file is like below.

```
  class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
   {
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $customerRepository;
     public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository

) {
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;        
    parent::__construct($context);
}
    public function getCurrentCustomer() {
      $customer = $this->customerSession->getCustomer();
      $customerId = $customer->getId();
      $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);

      return $customer;
    }
 }
```

Please anyone look the code and suggest me.Thanks

Comment: Did you checked it..? updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code :

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer
 */
protected $_customerSession;
protected $_customer;
/**
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer
 */
public function __construct(
    ...........
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
    ...........
){
    ...........
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_customer = $customer;
}

public function getCurrentCustomer()
{
    if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $customer_id = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
        $customerData = $this->_customer->load($customer_id);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, where to add this code?  in my Block file? can we use execute in block file?

Comment: Yes. you can use this code in your block. Add execute() function code in that function where you want to get.

Comment: Already the above code i am using in helper file method is getCurrentCustomer,  that function i am calling in Block file, why i need to construct here again?

Comment: You just need to add code From execute funtion to getCurrentCustomer function and inject \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer in your construct. Then, remove generate folder and clean cache.

Comment: I did, but same again, Please read my Block file, i am declaring a function to get current customer.

Comment: check my updated answer..I changed function name.Now, it's easy for you.

Comment: Yes fine, but Already i have function in helper file, that i am calling in Block file, to get it in template file. why to redefine again here. just can't call it from helper?

Comment: This code you can use in any file. Helper, controller or block. Anywhere you can use it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81093/discussion-between-jafar-and-rohan-hapani).

Comment: If you want to get data in template file. Then, you can directly access helper function in your template file.. No need to pass in block file.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:
1. Change constructor of block file(Lists) like below:

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \[vendor]\[Module]\Helper\Data $helperData,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->helperData = $helperData;
    }
```

2. Clear `var/di/*` and `generated/*`. Flush your cache and test again.

Comment: hello, i tried this code. Its not working

Comment: Check var/log/system.log file for any error. If there is not any error in log file then  put error_reporting(E_ALL) ;ini_set('display_errors',1); in magento's root index.php file.